# Power automate populate excel

Tags: azure-logic-apps, power-automate

I want that when a contract is signed the following information is entered in an excel table: Agreement ID, Agreement Name, Creation Date, Status. And if the row already exists changes the status.
But it doesn’t really work, it creates several rows each time.

[image: Logic app]

[image: Row in excel]

The foreach gives "False" to each operation while the line is existing

Comment: Sorry but you've missed providing the parts that help you diagnose the issue.  What are the values in the condition?  Can you provide some screenshots of the run results or something?!

Answer (score 0):

After reproducing from our end, we have observed that changing condition in the `condition` connector to below expression have updated the changes in excel, after using `List rows present in a table` connector before the `condition` connector. As it gets all the rows present in the table.

```
array(body('List_rows_present_in_a_table')?['value']?[0]?['Agreement ID'])
```

Here is my Logic App

[image]

Below is my excel initially

[image]

**Result:**

[image]